# Get value of hidden fields

Tags: jquery, onchange, prompt

I'm trying to fetch the value of hidden fields in form when update_qty is changed with an on change event. Form is generated by php loop and presents one row from DB. I need to fetch update_qty with onchange event and also get all the hidden fields of the updated row.

Below is code I'm using, can you please point me to the right direction? I can't get it to work. I always get values in hidden fields from the first row.

```
//This form is dynamiclly genrated buy php loop. All input fields are one row from DB. 

<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="update_qty.php">
<input type="text" name="update_qty" class="update_qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $sales_value['qty'] ?>"><?php echo ' Kom'; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="<?php echo $sales_value['article_id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sales_plan_id" id="sales_plan_id" value="<?php echo $sales_plan_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="product_mix_id" id="product_mix_id" value="<?php echo $product_mix_id; ?>">
</form>

    //Update qty on article
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.update_qty').on('change', function() {

        var message = prompt("Upišite razlog za izmjenu količine:");
        alert(message);
        //e.preventDefault();
        var article_id = $("#article_id").val();
        var sales_plan_id = $("#sales_plan_id").val();
        var update_qty = $(this).val();
        var product_mix_id = $("#product_mix_id").val();


        if (message != "" || message != NULL) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'update_qty.php',
                data:{ article_id: article_id, sales_plan_id: sales_plan_id, update_qty: update_qty, product_mix_id: product_mix_id, message: message },
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            e.PreventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Just ask one question please. Also, what do you mean by rows? Do we need to see html? please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi wazz. I have updated my post, so maybe my question is more clear now. Also, I have removed one question. I'm not very good with jquery, that's why I'm struggling. I have isolated my problem with connecting onchange event of class with the ID's of a hidden field which doesn't belong to that class. If I give the same class to each row, then I can't get update_qty to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may to serialise entire form instead to get all inputs:

```
$(function() {
  $('.update_qty').on('change', function(e) {
    var data = $('#form1').serializeArray();
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! Excellent solution.